# Extract multiple indices from matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want to access multiple indices of a matrix as shown below. So what I want is indices (1,3),(2,6),(3,7) to be set to one. However, as you can see the entire column is set to one. I can see what it is doing but is there a way to do what I want it to (in an elegant way - no loops).

```
a=zeros(3,10)
a(1:3,[3 6 7])=1

a =

 0     0     1     0     0     1     1     0     0     0
 0     0     1     0     0     1     1     0     0     0
 0     0     1     0     0     1     1     0     0     0
```

I realise that you can do something along the lines of

```
x_idx=1:3, y_idx=[3 6 7];
idx=x_idx*size(a,2)+y_idx;
a(idx)=1;
```

but just wondering if there was a better, or proper way of doing this in Matlab

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html), which essentially is doing what you have mentioned in your post, but MATLAB has this built-in:

```
a = zeros(3,10);
a(sub2ind(size(a), 1:3, [3 6 7])) = 1

a =

     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0
```

Another way would be to create a `logical` [`sparse`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) matrix, then use this to index into `a`:

```
a = zeros(3,10);
ind = logical(sparse(1:3, [3 6 7], true, size(a,1), size(a,2)));
a(ind) = 1

a =

     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0
```

Comment: +1... one suggestion instead of casting the sparse to logical you can directly create a sparse logical array which can be used for indexing... `ind = sparse(1:3, [3 6 7], true, size(a,1), size(a,2));`

Comment: @RTL - Ah yes.  I forgot about that.  Thanks!